# How to play a resources file in Windows Media Player from another control's tag in vb.NET

Tags: vb.net, embedded-resource, windows-media-player

I have a Picture Box which has a My.Resources link to a .mp3 file stored in the Tag property:

```
PictureBox1.Tag = My.Resources.AudioFile
```

I then try to load this into a Windows Media Player Object

```
Dim Player As New WindowsMediaPlayer
Player.URL = PictureBox1.Tag
Player.controls.play()
```

When I try this I get the error:

> Conversion from type 'Byte()' to type 'String' is not valid.

On a hunch I tried `My.Resources.AudioFile.ToString`but this produced the error:

> The selected file has an extension (.Byte[]) that is not recognized by Windows Media Player, but the Player may still be able to play it. Because the extension is unknown by the Player, you should be sure that the file comes from a trustworthy source.

I really don't want the user to have to accept this dialog every time a sound plays. Is there a way to convert play from a resources path?

Comment: WMP only supports playing from a file, you cannot directly use your resource.  Which would be a good reason to not use resources.  They also make your memory footprint rather large.  If you want to do this anyway then you have to write your resource to a file.  Pick any file, use File.WriteAllBytes() to write your resource to the file.  And set the URL property to that file.

Answer (score -1):

See the following code snippet

```
ResourceManager rm = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager;
SoundPlayer sound = new SoundPlayer();

sound.Stream = Properties.Resources.IntroSound;
sound.PlayLooping();
```